# Demandware (SFCC - Salesforce Commerce Cloud) Site Issue

Tags: demandware

I am new to Demandware and facing a very awkward issue. The website stops loading CSS and renders an ugly page randomly, this might happen when the same URL is running well in let's say CHROME, but if it's opened in incognito or some other browser, it fails and renders without styling.

Is it some caching issue in Sandbox? or something I am missing in configuration (all the caches are disabled in the sandbox)

Comment: The first thing I would check - Do you see any errors in the Request Log when the page does not load correctly?

Comment: Thanks, @GauravKheterpal request log is good, its happening randomly on the same browser for the same URL.

Comment: I have seen a similar issue with JS files occasionally not loading/rendering recently. However, that I've only seen on instances that were behind the eCDN (CloudFlare). I hope you figure it out, I've not seen your specific issue before.